# Python: If any value(Y) from a list is smaller than a constant, remove Y's corresponding index from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is: If any value from my aList is smaller than a constant variable, I want to take index of that lower value and delete sth from a bList corresponding to that index. Shortly, I want to compare all the values in aList to a constant and if there is a lower value in aList than constant. I will get the index of these and using that index making `bList[index]= 0.`

Example:

Lets say

```
constantToCompare=8
aList=[13, 12, 11, 9, 7]     
bList=[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
```

So 5th element of `aList` is smaller than `constantToCompare`

I want to make `bList` = `[100, 200, 300, 400, 0]`

By the way this `constantToCompare` will increase by +1 up to some  so that a loop required to do this process.

Thank you.
I hope I am clear.

Comment: You should try something by yourself first and then post any doubts to this site

Comment: Yeah you are _clear_ , but we should write this code for you?

Comment: I just need to learn what to use and what to know, I am just beginner at python and I am stuck at this part of the question.

Comment: Do you want to delete the corresponding element or do you want to set it to zero? These are very different!

Comment: @colopop set it to 0 , sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're a beginner, I'll try to break down the steps clearly. You want to iterate through `aList`. Since you care about the index of each element as well as the element itself, you'll want to use [`enumerate`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html):

```
for idx, val in enumerate(aList):
```

Inside this loop, you'll be able to use `idx` to get the value of the current index and `val` to get the value of the element you're currently looking at. Then you want to check if `val` is less than a constant:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(aList):
   if val < constantToCompare:
```

And if it is, set the corresponding element in `bList` to zero:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(aList):
   if val < constantToCompare:
      bList[idx] = 0
```

For a more concise look, you can instead use a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) (a fast way to create a list):

```
bList = [bList[idx] for idx, val in enumerate(aList) if val >= constantToCompare else 0]
```

I'm not sure what you mean about `constantToCompare` increasing. If you want to do this several times, you can wrap it all in another loop:

```
for constantToCompare in range(start_val, end_val+1):
   bList = [bList[idx] for idx, val in enumerate(aList) if val >= constantToCompare else 0]
```

If you want it to increase as you go through the list, you can add another line to the loop:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(aList):
   if val < constantToCompare:
      bList[idx] = 0
   constantToCompare += 1
```

I used the list comprehension for conciseness, but in actual code I might prefer the longer version for readability.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below code .This is tested code hope this will solve your  problem.

```
constantToCompare=8
aList=[13, 12, 11, 9, 7,1,2,2] 
bList=[100, 200, 300, 400, 500,12,3,56]
for i in range(0,len(aList)):
    if(constantToCompare>aList[i]):
        bList[i]=0
print(bList)
```

Comment: This only works if `aList` contains only unique values.

Comment: so you want 0 in bList at all places where aList's element are less than  constantToCompare?

Comment: @mesboomin please test it is working fine .please let me know if any thing is required from my side

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to achieve this task.

```
constant_to_compare = 8
a_list = [13, 12, 11, 9, 7]     
b_list = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
b_list = [element[1] if element[0] > constant_to_compare else 0 for element in zip(a_list, b_list)]
```

`zip` together the data that belongs together and then decide whether you want to keep the original value or set it to `0`.

In the question you said that the value used for the comparison will change by `+1` during the processing. You can't work with this approach if `constant_to_compare` should change during the processing of one loop. I'm not sure if this is the case or if you want to do the whole process multiple times. Whatever it is, the "constant" part of the variable name is misleading and should be changed.

Comment: Since OP is new to python, they could probably use some explanation on what's going on in that list comprehension.